# Secure Wordpress file uploader (front end)

Tags: wordpress, file, security, upload

I'm building a site for a client in Wordpress and I want to know if there's a recommended and secure way for files to be sent. 
My client wants to allow her users to send her pictures as part of the service she offers.

Is there a way this can be done and more importantly, securely?

I'm open to alternative suggestions, just didn't want to pull the user away from the site to send via email (even though that will be an option also).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that as long as your site has SSL (preferably across the whole domain, but at least on the particular page) and you use the proper element (`<input type="file" name="picture-file">`) it's secure.